# Print a PDF file with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I know that there are similar questions about this issues but not a single one seems to address my problem.

I have two options In my widget: one that allows the user to save the display as PDF file and one that allows the user to print the display directly.

My problem is that there seems to be quite some minor differences if I print the saved PDF file with Windows vs when I print the interface with Qt. A possible solution that I begin to follow is that when I print the interface first to save the interface in PDF as a temporary file and after to try to print with Qt that file.

Unfortunately it seems that I can not use directly the PDF file without convert it in a pixmap or something similar.

This is how I manage to export in PDF format:

```
   QTextDocument doc;
   if (!ComputeDoc(doc))
     return false;

  QPrinter printer;
  printer.setOutputFileName(filePath);
  printer.setPaperSize(format);
  printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
  printer.setOrientation (orientation);
  printer.setFullPage(true);

  if(ok && !filePath.isEmpty())
  {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
    painter.setRenderHint(
      (QPainter::RenderHint)(int)(
        QPainter::Antialiasing            |
        QPainter::TextAntialiasing        |
        QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing |
        QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform),
      true);

      painter.setPen(Qt::white);        
      doc.drawContents(&painter);
   }
```

And this how I originally try to print the file:

```
  QTextDocument doc;
  if (!ComputeDoc(doc))
    return false;

  QPrinter printer;
  printer.setPaperSize(format);
  printer.setOrientation (orientation);
  printer.setFullPage(true);

  QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer, this);

  if(ok && printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
  {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
    painter.setRenderHint(
      (QPainter::RenderHint)(int)(
        QPainter::Antialiasing            |
        QPainter::TextAntialiasing        |
        QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing |
        QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform),
      true);

    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    doc.drawContents(&painter);
  }
```

[image]

As you can see from the print the inner frame is not centered and in the left part (the image is flipped to right) of the paper there is a line that in PDF is not. Sorry for this example but I can not post the entire page. I hope this will give a small clarification.

Does anyone know a solution to print a PDF file from the disk with qt? Or maybe how to make Windows to print to file from qt?

Comment: You could show an image by pointing out the differences.

Comment: I posted an image.

Comment: You can provide the code that makes the drawing of the lines